# Get the title of the original page in your default language and add it as body class to the translated page on WordPress with WPML

Tags: wordpress, class, filter, title, wpml

Here's my problem:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'wpml_body_class');
function wpml_body_class( $class ) {
    global $sitepress, $post;

    if( $sitepress->get_default_language() != ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE ) {
        $original_id = icl_object_id( $post->ID, get_post_type(), true, $sitepress->get_default_language() );
        $class[] = strtolower(get_the_title( $original_id ));
    }

    return $class;
}
```

This code works fine. Essentially, I use $sitepress as a global to get my default language and then I extract the ID to match it with get_the_title, so, at the end of the day, I added the title as a class name to the body, so I can easily replicate the style of the original page without adding a line on my CSS stylesheet file on the translated page, in this case in French.

So far so good, except for a caveat:

Since this is the title, if I have a title like Our Team, I have to add a dash to the style, and it is going to change base on how many words I have. If I have to use the URL instead, the process to extract it with WordPress is more complex, so I was wondering if it is possible to add a regular expression to add a dash if I have any space. Or if everyone else knows how to extract the URL instead of get_the_title I couldn't be more grateful.

Comment: what you need is `sanitize_title_with_dashes()` for your purpose :)

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Please write as an answer so I can mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need is `sanitize_title_with_dashes()` for your purpose :) which is provided by WP .  Reference https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title_with_dashes